# Not able to find Xpath for Parent Child relation in Div tag

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

[image]

[image]

Hi 
I am not able to find the correct xpath for the Html code added in the attachment.

I have written below xpath but it is not working.

```
//div[@class="calendar-item-title"][1]//*[@class="calendar-item-time"][1]
```

Please find attached image for more details of Html code.

Comment: //div[@class="calendar-item-title"][1]//*[@class="calendar-item-time"][1]

I have used above xpath but it is not able to find an element.Please suggest correct xpath.

Comment: please add an appropriate image to the question, also move your comment details to the question

Comment: I have tried below XPath as well but it is not working  ///div[contains(@class,'container')]//a[2]

Answer (score 0):

`div[@class="calendar-item-title"]` does not have a child `*[@class="calendar-item-time"]` according to your image.

Your `*[@class="calendar-item-time"]` is in `div[@class="items-container"]` 
so your xpath would be:

`//div[@class="items-container"][1]//a[@class="calendar-item-time"][1]`

Comment: Tried above Xpath but it is not working.Getting an Error as Element Not Found.

Answer (score 0):

Just add : "/parent::*" at the end of //div[@class="calendar-item-title"] if you want the parent element

Comment: No,I want the child element.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath :

```
//a[contains(text(),'12:30 am')]
```

Answer (score 0):

try with the below xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='12:30 am']")).click()
```

from ur image, its not clear there are more 12.30  containing text or not. In that case, use

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[text()='12:30 am']")).get(0).click();
```